# Why I can't see the references?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

This seems very simple, but I can't figure out why it doesn't show citation? I do have two files: test.tex, and test.bib

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

bla bla .... \cite{tets}


\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

and here is the bib file:

```
@article{test,


title={Molecular biology for computer scientists},
  author={Hunter, L.},
  journal={Artificial intelligence and molecular biology},
  pages={1--46},
  year={1993},
  publisher={AAAI Press/MIT Press, Menlo Park, CA}
}
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Have you run `(pdf)latex` -> `bibtex` -> `(pdf)latex` -> `(pdf)latex`? In other words, what is the process you use to compile the document?

Comment: I use Typeset with Texshop. I don't think my latex has any problem, because I use it to write my thesis. I just wanted to pick up part of my thesis with the references.

Comment: Problem it's not that. still I have nothing cited.

Answer (score 3):

Mispelled line corrected.  It is assumed, that you a going to use `latex`, `bibtex` and twice `latex` (or another command, like `pdflatex`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

%bla bla .... \cite{tets}
bla bla .... \cite{test}


\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, still it doesn't show the reference.

Comment: @Maryam Are you using your `test` in place of `test2`?

Comment: yes, what you mean test2. I save my bib text : test.bib

Comment: @Maryam I have just changed `test2` into `test` after `\bibliography`. In general, the same name for different objects is the source of problems, hence my previous change.

Comment: I found the problem. It doesn't work directly with Typeset (and I don't know why?). I complied through terminal, and works.

Comment: @Maryam But after correcting `\cite{tets}` into `\cite{test}`?

Comment: yes. but now there is another problem. compiling the main text through terminal gives me this error: Cannot determine size of graphic in...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15715/discussion-between-maryam-and-przemyslaw-scherwentke).